# HTML/CSS: YouTube iframe as background with controls usable and button overlay

Tags: html, css, button, youtube, controls

I just fooled around with HTML/CSS to build me a page with a youtube-video with a button on top of it.

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
.video-background {
  background: #000;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  z-index: -99;
}
.video-background iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.btn-wrapper {
  width: 290px;
  height: 110px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 40px auto 0;
}
.btn-wrapper:hover .btn-inner {
  top: -4px;
  transform: scale(1, 1);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.btn-wrapper__container {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #15b5e2;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
}
.btn-wrapper__container:before, .btn-wrapper__container:after {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #15b5e2;
  width: 96%;
  left: 2%;
  bottom: -8px;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
}
.btn-wrapper__container:after {
  width: 92%;
  left: 4%;
  bottom: -14px;
}
.btn-wrapper__container .btn-inner {
  width: 104.2%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: -2.1%;
  border: 2px solid #15b5e2;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #10131c;
  transform: scale(0.96, 0.96);
  transition: all 0.3s;
  z-index: 4;
}
.btn-wrapper__container .btn-inner__text {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #15b5e2;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-background">
  <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/TMzouTzim0o?controls=1&showinfo=0&rel=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=W0LHTWG-UmQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>


<div class="btn-wrapper">
  <div class="btn-wrapper__container">
    <div class="btn-inner">
      <a class="btn-inner__text" href="#">Hover Me</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

While without the button added, the video is shown in background, responsive and fullscreen, with control-elements enabled. If i add the hover-button, I am no longer able to control the video in background (360 video).

How can I enable the controls of the video and still have the button usable?

I am unfortunately not a coding expert, I've puzzled these pieces together of code I found in tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove css property `z-index: -99` from class `.video-background {...}`, that will fix the issue.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.video-background {
  background: #000;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  /* z-index: -99; */ /* Remove this line  */
}

.video-background iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.btn-wrapper {
  width: 290px;
  height: 110px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 40px auto 0;
}

.btn-wrapper:hover .btn-inner {
  top: -4px;
  transform: scale(1, 1);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-wrapper__container {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #15b5e2;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
}

.btn-wrapper__container:before,
.btn-wrapper__container:after {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #15b5e2;
  width: 96%;
  left: 2%;
  bottom: -8px;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
}

.btn-wrapper__container:after {
  width: 92%;
  left: 4%;
  bottom: -14px;
}

.btn-wrapper__container .btn-inner {
  width: 104.2%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: -2.1%;
  border: 2px solid #15b5e2;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #10131c;
  transform: scale(0.96, 0.96);
  transition: all 0.3s;
  z-index: 4;
}

.btn-wrapper__container .btn-inner__text {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #15b5e2;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-background">
  <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/TMzouTzim0o?controls=1&showinfo=0&rel=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=W0LHTWG-UmQ"
    frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<div class="btn-wrapper">
  <div class="btn-wrapper__container">
    <div class="btn-inner">
      <a class="btn-inner__text" href="#">Hover Me</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```